# 8086 can't access to external memory

Tags: assembly, x86-16

we're working on a proteus simulation that actually has 8x(2KB) external memory (6116) but as we tried so far can't access to external memory. The Question said that external memory address should start at 0x14000 and we designed the proper decoder logic; and tried three ways to access such an address as below:

**Goal: to move a value from internal registers to external memory startng at 0x14000**

1- using ORG & MOV instruction together
2- using ORG $ PUSH-POP instruction together
3- without using ORG instruction + moving 1400 to DS (DataSegmentRegister)

but non of them worked
any help would be appreciated

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Eznyj0pQfS2ccj5eIesYnnle01v2ftId

Comment: try moving 0x1400 to DS (segments are 16 bytes each). ORG is just relevant for code

Comment: thank you for your quick res. actually did this but didn't work.

Comment: show the actual code you wrote. `mov ax,0x1400` `mov ds,ax` and `mov byte ptr [0], cl` should write CL to 0x14000

Comment: still doesn't work. could you please look at this...as we simulated the design. the address decoder is never enabled...https://srv-file4.gofile.io/download/hmeZyl/04_main_8086.PDF

Comment: Your link is broken.  "You are not authorized to download this file".  If you have new information to add to your question, edit it in.  Definitely do not just post it in off-site links.  If that instruction sequence didn't work, your system is broken or it didn't actually run.  It stores to `1400:0000` which is linear address `0x14000`.

Comment: the PDF can't be opened. Did you try a minimalistic encoder. just mapping A0-A10 to any of the chips + what's needed to determine memory access? (RW, mem and stuff ?) if you leave A11 and up unconnected, one 2k memory block will be shadowed all over the address range

Comment: sorry for the broken link. google drive link attached to the question.

Comment: This site is for software development questions. Circuit design is off-topic.

Comment: Why can't you include a [mcve] in your question?  Presumably that Google Drive link will break at some point and then this question will be useless to future readers.

Comment: @interjay: That's not strictly true.  We have tags for [tag:verilog] and [tag:vhdl].  But those are generally for designing ASICs and FPGAs, not wiring up a whole computer with CPU + RAM.  We do have [tag:cpu-architecture] for questions about how CPUs work (which is often useful to know how to optimize for them.)  But I would tend to agree this specific question seems to be getting more into electronics.SE territory.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think Verilog and VHDL should be on https://electronics.stackexchange.com as well. But at least those are languages somewhat similar to software programming languages. In this question all we get is a circuit diagram, which is surely off-topic.

Comment: @interjay: Agreed.  I decided to post an answer to the software part of this question because we have enough for the SO-relevant parts of it to be answerable.

Answer (score 0):

ORG only tells the compiler where to expect the code (and static data) to be in memory.  (so `mov ax, OFFSET my_label` can assemble to the right numeric address).  It's not what you need for this, unless you're *loading* your code at this high address and have nearby data with labels on it.

Instead, you can set DS (and/or ES) to a numeric value and use an offset relative to that to to address memory.

```
mov  ax, 0x1400
mov  ds, ax
mov  byte ptr [0], cl
```

That stores a byte (from CL) to `1400:000`, which in real mode is linear address `0x14000`.

**If that doesn't do what you want, then you also have a (virtual) hardware problem, not a software problem**.  Perhaps ask about that part on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

**one possible solution was to write the first memory access (only), twice.**
this may related to a bug in Proteus and it's really strange

as you can see, the **00h** memory access instructions repeated twice but for others like **01h** instructions are normally worked without repeating 
and the working snippet was sth like the following ...

```
MOV AX,DATA_HERE
MOV DS, AX

MOV AX,1400H
MOV DS , AX

MOV CL,07H
MOV BX,00h
MOV [BX],CL

MOV CL,09H
MOV BX,00h
MOV [BX],CL

MOV CL,08h
MOV BX,01h
MOV [BX],CL
```